# Converting character values to numeric in SAS

Tags: character-encoding, sas

i have a data set exam.

the values are:
(Both the variables are character)

exam1
24
56
78
ND

exam2
35
56
ND
45

This is the task i have to perform:
Using select statement,convert the exam values to numeric such that when exam value is ND, exam value must be assigned 0 otherwise it should just convert from character to numeric using the input function .

I have tried with this code:

```
data work.ex(drop = Ex1 Ex2);

set home.exam(rename=(exam1=Ex1) (exam2=Ex2))

select ;

when (exam1='ND') exam1=0;

otherwise exam1=input(Ex1,3.0);

end;
```

But this is not converting it to numeric

Comment: Please update the question with the names of columns of data set exam.

Comment: The column names are exam1 and exam2.  The data set is exam

Answer (score 0):

`proc sql;
     select 
     case when exam1 = 'ND' then 0
     else input(exam1,2.) end as exam1,
     case when exam2 = 'ND' then 0
     else input(exam2,2.) end as exam2
     from exam;
   quit;`

Increase the value `2.` if you have larger than 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Select statement works like this:

```
Data want;
Set have;
Select(var);
When(1) ...;
When(2) ...;
When(3) ...;
Otherwise ...;
End;
Run;
```

1 2 3 are logical statements of your choice (like, `var=7`).  ... Is whatever you want to do if that is true like `var2=1;`.